# Linq where clause compare only date value without time value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, linq-to-entities, compare

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
    .tbl_MyTable
    .Where(x => x.Active == true
        && x.DateTimeValueColumn <= DateTime.Now)
    .Select(x => x);
```

Upper query is working correct.
 
But I want to check only date value only.
But upper query check date + time value.

In traditional mssql, I could write query like below.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_MyTable
WHERE 
CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DateTimeValueColumn, 102) AS DATE) <= 
            CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),102) AS DATE)
AND
Active = 1
```

So could anyone give me suggestion how could I check only date value in Linq.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There is also `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` or **`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`** in EF 6.0 or later

Comment: Replace EntityFunctions with DbFunctions if you an error as EntitiyFunction is deprcated.

Comment: This worked great. Just a note that you can (actually must) use TruncateTime on both the database column as well as the C# DateTime.Now. Here is the LINQ statement I used: `mydata.Where(t => t.ExpirationDate == null || (t.ExpirationDate != null && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.ExpirationDate.Value) > DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)));`

Comment: DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now) = DateTime.Today ?

Comment: I would more appreciated this answer if it was contains an example of using those functions, Or at least make reference to some resource which contains some example

Comment: what about EF Core 1.0?

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 20):

**Simple workaround to this problem to compare date part only**

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
                    .tbl_MyTable
                    .Where(x => x.Active == true && 
                               x.DateTimeValueColumn.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                            && x.DateTimeValueColumn.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                            && x.DateTimeValueColumn.Day == DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Because 'Date' datatype is not supported by linq to entity , where as Year, Month and Day are 'int' datatypes and are supported.

Comment: It check for ==, not <=. Of course with some more conditions that can be achieved.

Comment: come on, you never heard of DbFunctions.TruncateTime?

Comment: This becomes longwinded if you need to check a date using the comparator '<' or '>'.

Comment: Is there at TruncateOffset function to get the DateTime part of a DateTimeOffset?  Seems impossible to refer to the DateTime part of a DateTimeOffset with entity framework, which makes it quite useless.

Comment: hi, can you wrap this in an EF extension so that it can be reused all over?

Comment: This gets messy really fast.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

To avoid this error : The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to  Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are  supported.

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
                .tbl_MyTable
                .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                         .Select(x => x).ToList();

 var filterdata = _My_ResetSet_Array
        .Where(x=>DateTime.Compare(x.DateTimeValueColumn.Date, DateTime.Now.Date)  <= 0 );
```

The second line is required because LINQ to Entity is not able to convert date property to sql query. So its better to first fetch the data and then apply the date filter.

**EDIT**

If you just want to compare the date value of the date time than make use of

[`DateTime.Date` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) - Gets the date component of this instance.

Code for you

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
                .tbl_MyTable
                .Where(x => x.Active == true
     && DateTime.Compare(x.DateTimeValueColumn.Date, DateTime.Now.Date)  <= 0 )
                         .Select(x => x);
```

---

If its like that then use

[DateTime.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) - Compares two instances of DateTime and returns an integer that indicates whether the first instance is earlier than, the same as, or later than the second instance.

Code for you

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
                .tbl_MyTable
                .Where(x => x.Active == true
                  && DateTime.Compare(x.DateTimeValueColumn, DateTime.Now)  <= 0 )
                         .Select(x => x);
```

Example

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you that Exception return `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but nothing change.

Comment: @Frank - thanks for the reply ..just forget to include ToList() function ...so code is updated in answer it like this after adding list function var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
                    .tbl_MyTable
                    .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                             .Select(x => x).ToList()

Comment: @Frank- i also provided one work around try out that this will might work for you...

Comment: -1 for "First fetch the data and then compare", assuming a 1TB database with active records, you will download all just to remove 700GB (in the time range).

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
 result = from r in result where (r.Reserchflag == true && 
    (r.ResearchDate.Value.Date >= FromDate.Date && 
     r.ResearchDate.Value.Date <= ToDate.Date)) select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

> `&& x.DateTimeValueColumn <= DateTime.Now`

This is supported so long as your schema is correct

```
&& x.DateTimeValueColumn.Value.Date <=DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Except it's not. He's using Linq to Entities, not normal linq.

Answer (score 1):

In similar case I used the following code:

```
DateTime upperBound = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); // If today is October 9, then upperBound is set to 2012-10-10 00:00:00
return var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
    .tbl_MyTable
    .Where(x => x.Active == true
        && x.DateTimeValueColumn < upperBound) // Accepts all dates earlier than October 10, time of day doesn't matter here
    .Select(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code :

```
     {
        DataBaseEntity db = new DataBaseEntity (); //This is EF entity
        string dateCheck="5/21/2018";
        var list= db.tbl
        .where(x=>(x.DOE.Value.Month
              +"/"+x.DOE.Value.Day
              +"/"+x.DOE.Value.Year)
             .ToString()
             .Contains(dateCheck))
     }
```

Comment: Please wrap your code sample in code block formatting for easy reading.

Comment: I am considering the query performance since you are using string value to compare.

Comment: Thank u man... This code can combine the date to a string and help to search the date from the database to a list...

Comment: What type of error ? can you explain please... @habib

Comment: @Soharab you query will work definitely with lEnumberable but not with IQueryable because entity framework will say oh I don't know what is meant by.Month or Value.Day because entity framework first converts this into the query and then run. For further please try this you will be know what error maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var _My_ResetSet_Array = _DB
    .tbl_MyTable
    .Where(x => x.Active == true
         && x.DateTimeValueColumn <= DateTime.Now)
    .Select(x => x.DateTimeValueColumn)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .select(p=>p.DateTimeValueColumn.value.toString("YYYY-MMM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not simplify the code to avoid "linq translation error":
The test consist between a date with time at 0:0:0 and the same date with time at 23:59:59

```
        iFilter.MyDate1 = DateTime.Today;  // or DateTime.MinValue

        // GET 
        var tempQuery = ctx.MyTable.AsQueryable();

        if (iFilter.MyDate1 != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            TimeSpan temp24h = new TimeSpan(23,59,59);
            DateTime tempEndMyDate1 = iFilter.MyDate1.Add(temp24h);

            // DO not change the code below, you need 2 date variables...
            tempQuery = tempQuery.Where(w => w.MyDate2 >= iFilter.MyDate1
                                          && w.MyDate2 <= tempEndMyDate1);
        }

        List<MyTable> returnObject = tempQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score -4):

Use `mydate.Date` to work with the date part of the DateTime class only.

Comment: see the solution in my answer ...Date property will not work in linq to entity